# PagedList MVC stay on the same page after a post

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I have a view where the side menu (where PagedList is populating data with no problems) that are also links to display another set of data on the same view. Once these links are clicked, I want to have the data on that field to be changed and have the side menu (PagedList) to stay on the same page. I can pass the id value to my controller and display the data, but the "page number" value is not being passed.
Any ideas on how to accomplish that.

Here's what my code looks like

```
  [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(string id, int? page)
        {
            try
            {
                id = Request.Form["newsLinkButton"];                
                ViewBag.Id = id;
                using (myEntities db = new myEntities())
                {                    
                    var getNews = db.News.Where(x => x.Show == "Yes").OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).ToList();
                    return View(getNews.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 5));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {                    
                return View(ex);
            }
        }  

<div class="sidebar blue-sidebar news-sidebar no-mobile">
                    <h2>Recent News</h2>
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "News", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <form id="newsForm" name="newsForm">
                            <ul class="white-text">
                                @foreach (var item in Model.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date))
                                {
                                    <li>
                                        <button id="newsLinkButton" name="newsLinkButton" type="submit" value="@item.Id">@item.Title</button>
                                    </li>
                                    }
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                        <div class="center-block">  
                                @Html.PagedListPager(Model, page => Url.Action("Index", new { page }),
                                         new PagedListRenderOptions()
                                         {

                                             DisplayLinkToFirstPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
                                             DisplayLinkToPreviousPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
                                             DisplayLinkToLastPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
                                             DisplayLinkToNextPage = PagedListDisplayMode.Always,
                                             MaximumPageNumbersToDisplay = 3, // number of pages in line
                                             DisplayEllipsesWhenNotShowingAllPageNumbers = false
                                         })

                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
```

Once again, thanks for your help in advance. I appreciate.

Comment: I think you have several mistakes here, such like `page => Url.Action("Index", new { page })` which only passes one parameter. Can you mention both `id` and `page` parameter values received inside `Index` action?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, thanks for your reply, the id is actually bein set here  "id = Request.Form["newsLinkButton"];" and I kind of want to do the same with the page. Where does the page value comes from in PagedList? Do you happen to know?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto, I've ended up finding that property on my own. That was the PageNumber. I then created a Session Variable to hold that value and passed to the controller. It is working as expected now.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the property PageNumber is what holds the value for the page number (yeah, I know huh?). Therefore, I created `@{ Session["page"] = Model.PageNumber; }` and passed on to the controller. Problem solved. I hope this can help someone else in the future.